# S3 consistency issue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

Unable to completely read data from S3 if read happens right after s3 location is updated with new data

I am using S3 to store some data in parquet file format. This data gets updated (overwrite) after few hours everyday. The problem is when read operation happens at the time when s3 locations are being updated with new data, read operation gives partial data . I tried populating different S3 keys and then syncing live s3 location using s3 sync command but still I get partial read issue if read happens during s3 sync. Thinking if this is right approach to store data to S3?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are describing is exactly the one that is tackled by Delta Lake, created, and open-sourced recently by Databricks. This should mostly solve your issue of reading partial data or stale data.

Refer:

- https://delta.io/
- https://docs.databricks.com/delta/index.html